# WPML get translated content of a string from all languages if available

Tags: wordpress, wpml

Using WPML, I have translated a string in 4 languages say: en, nl, fr and de.

By default I can use `<?php _e('my string here','text_domain'); ?>` and it will return the exact translated text when I am in that domain.

How can I get all the translated texts in one place. So If I am on english version of the website but I would like to get the translated content for my string in nl, fr, de and en.

May I know how is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could temporary change the current language to retrieve the translated string. Something like:

```
// Backup the current language
$current_lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();  // Say it's "en"

// Switch to another language. E.g. $desired_lang = "nl";
$sitepress->switch_lang( $desired_lang );

// Get your translated string...
_e( 'My string here', 'text_domain' );

// Back to the original language to not interfere
$sitepress->switch_lang( $current_lang );
```

I've tested this on a page template (say `index.php`) and it works... Then I tried to build a function to do the job. Something like:

```
// Put this in your functions.php
function get_all_translations( $string, $languages ) {

    global $sitepress;

    if ( empty( $languages ) ) {
        $languages = array_keys(
            icl_get_languages( 'skip_missing=0&orderby=code&order=asc' )
        );
    }

    $current_lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();

    $translations = [];
    foreach ( $languages as $lang ) {
        $sitepress->switch_lang( $lang, true );
        $translations[$lang] = __( $string, 'text_domain' );
    }

    $sitepress->switch_lang( $current_lang );
    return $translations;
}
```

And:

```
// This on index.php:
var_dump( get_all_translations( 'My string here' ) );
var_dump( get_all_translations( 'My string here', ['nl', 'fr'] ) );
```

But it doesn't work and I can't figure out the reason... I hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I just switched the language in 3 other languages, stored the strings in variables and used them.